# Do new installs of 17.10 have a "cog" at sign-in to choose display server?

Tags: gdm, display-manager

I have 3 installations of 17.10. Two are upgrades from previous versions, which were done a month or so ago. These are vms on a Mac (MBP); one on Fusion and one on Virtualbox. These two installs present me a cog at sign-in that allows me to switch display servers.

A couple of days ago, I installed a new Ubuntu 17.10 from a live usb on a new computer (as a dual boot with Windows 10). I note that it does not provide a cog @ sign-in. The display server is x11 (the response to "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE") which is fine by me.

It is not critical that I know the reason for this, but I am curious about the status of Wayland - and if I should have the ability to choose Wayland @ sign-in.

Comment: There should be a Wayland option, but most probably it's disabled by your hardware.

Comment: And it also depends on what DE you are running. As far as I know gnome is the only DE ready for prime time on wayland.

Answer (score 0):

17.10 runs per default on Wayland (at least the normal Gnome version of it runs on Wayland by default). The cogwheel is for cases when you have programs which wont work with Wayland like the most screen-recorders and VNC programs.

For this reason you have the ability to switch back to Xorg at login. If however your computer is not capable of running Wayland you are set by default to Xorg and then you will see no cogwheel to chose the display manager, it would only turn up if you for example install a second desktop environment.